Ubuntu 24.04 how to modify the sample rate in the Audio Output
I use Raspberry Pi5 installed Ubuntu 24.04. This is my first time using Ubuntu. When I connect my DAC Ubuntu identifies the sound output device as "Combo384 Amanero" in "Setting\Sound\Output\Output Device". My DAC displays the sample rates is 48 Khz. How can I set the sample rate to 96khz or other? Any apps or command in terminal to change?
Thank you for your kindly attention.
